# how to auto synchronize sources from svn and auto execute execute maven build and send email in case of failure

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, maven

I have a windows machine were I want to auto synchronize sources from svn either in eclipse or tortoise svn and when sync is done then I want to run maven build automatically and send email in case of failure..Please note this machine will not be used for development so no question of svn conflict.
Please let me know any hint in this regard,how can i solve the problem ? do we have any utility in maven which can do this for me?

Comment: Install Jenkins with a trigger from SVN (Hook Script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any continues Integration server for this.
Jenkin CI server details [check here](http://jenkins-ci.org/).
For auto-synchronization:
Open Synchronization view(Windows->Show View->Other and type Synchronize). Open the menu of this view by clicking down arrow button(Right most button in the view) then you will get

[image]

Click on schedule and provide required info

[image]